# Why I have a trouble after first click in updatepanel and repeater?

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, repeater

I'm having a trouble with updatepanel and repeater. I have repeater which is in updatepanel and I have a div which is inside another updatepanel. So in repeater I have also GroupRadioButton. When radiobutton checkedchanged div is displaying. Normally we can't reach repeater items outside. So I code it in itemdatabound. Works normal for first click. But second click page is postback. How can I fix it?

Here is my repeater and itemdatabound event.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upUsers" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="content">
            <asp:Repeater id="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
                <vs:GroupRadioButton ID="rbChoose" GroupName="grup1" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="select_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
                ... another control etc ...
            </asp:Repeater>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

there are some buttons and controls between both two updatepanels ...

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upUserDetails" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="content">
            <div id="divUserDetails" runat="server">
                ... details ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>


protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        ScriptManager sm = (ScriptManager)Master.FindControl("scr");
        AsyncPostBackTrigger trigger = new AsyncPostBackTrigger();
        GroupRadioButton rbChoose = e.Item.FindControl("rbChoose") as GroupRadioButton;
        sm.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(rbChoose);
        trigger.ControlID = rbChoose.ID;
        upUserDetails.Triggers.Add(trigger);
        upUserDetails.UpdateMode = UpdatePanelUpdateMode.Always;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry question not clear "Normally we can't reach repeater items outside."

Have you done check of !IsPostBack in pageLoad

Comment: I mean in aspx side, you can't say <triggers><asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="rbChoose" /></triggers> Because it's repeater item.

Comment: Have you done check of !IsPostBack in pageLoad